# Sumar en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentado realizar una factura que me sume los input en tiempo real, y ya básicamente "Lo tengo", pero lo que necesito es que no sea "obligatorio" llenar un input para que me muestre los resultados, que a medida de que vaya añadiendo valores se vayan mostrando, no al final ya cuando todos estén llenos.

Dejo la funcion Js que tengo hasta el momento, espero me puedan ayudar

```
function cal() {
   try {
var a = parseInt(document.frmFactura.Cuota.value),
    b = parseInt(document.frmFactura.Saldo.value),
    c = parseInt(document.frmFactura.Areas.value),
    d = parseInt(document.frmFactura.CuotaExtra.value);


document.frmFactura.nuevoSaldo.value = a + b + c + d ;
    } catch (e) {
   }
}
```

este es el archivo html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cuota" name="Cuota" value="95000" onchange="cal()" onkeypress="cal()" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Saldo" name="Saldo" onchange="cal()" onkeypress="cal()" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Areas" name="Areas" placeholder="Vehiculo, Moto, Salon Comunal" onchange="cal()" onkeypress="cal()" >
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="CuotaExtra" name="CuotaExtra" onchange="cal()">
```

Comment: ¿Los campos vacíos se considerarían como 0 (cero)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con el evento `onchange` puedes determinar cuando un input a cambiado, en ese momento actualizas el **total general**. Puedes agrupar los `input` por clase de esta forma le asignas un `addEventListener` a cada item, te dejo un ejemplo como hacerlo.

Ejemplo:

```js
items = document.getElementsByClassName("itemTotalNeto")
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 items[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
  n = document.getElementById("totalGeneral");
  n.value = parseInt("0"+n.value) + parseInt("0"+this.value) - parseInt("0"+this.defaultValue);
 this.defaultValue = this.value;
 });
};
```

```html
<input class="itemTotalNeto"><br>
<input class="itemTotalNeto"><br>
<input class="itemTotalNeto"><br>
<input class="itemTotalNeto"><br>
<input class="itemTotalNeto"><br>
Total General<br>
<input id="totalGeneral"><br>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu aporte, me ha funcionado bastante bien

Answer (score 1):

Lo tenías casi hecho, realmente lo único que tienes que hacer es añadir un `|| 0` a la asignación de valores. De ese modo lo que estarás haciendo es asignar el valor y, si no hay ninguno o es inválido, que se asigne el 0 como valor por defecto. Por ejemplo:

```
var a = parseInt(document.frmFactura.Cuota.value) || 0;
```

lo que hará es asignar el valor numérico que haya en `Cuota` a la variable `a`, y si el valor de `Cuota` no existe o está vacío, se le asigna 0.

---

Aparte de eso he hecho algunos cambios más en el código (aunque si lo que tenías antes te funcionaba más o menos, realmente no los necesitas):

- He cambiado el selector por un `getElementById` (para que me funcione en la demo de abajo).
- He cambiado los eventos por `onchange` y `onkeypressed` por uno solo: `oninput` que se ejecutará cada vez cambie el campo (para ahorrar algo de espacio, aunque idealmente deberías separa controlador y vista y asociar los eventos con `addEventListener`).

Con esos tres cambios el código se ve así:

```js
function cal() {
  try {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("Cuota").value) || 0,
      b = parseInt(document.getElementById("Saldo").value) || 0,
      c = parseInt(document.getElementById("Areas").value) || 0,
      d = parseInt(document.getElementById("CuotaExtra").value) || 0;

    document.getElementById("nuevoSaldo").value = a + b + c + d;
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cuota" name="Cuota" value="95000" oninput="cal()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Saldo" name="Saldo" oninput="cal()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Areas" name="Areas" placeholder="Vehiculo, Moto, Salon Comunal" oninput="cal()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="CuotaExtra" name="CuotaExtra" oninput="cal()">
<input id="nuevoSaldo" placeholder="Total" />
```

Comment: Oye muchas Gracias voy a probar a ver si me funciona, porque lo estaba intentando con ajax, pero al poner  ng-model="CuotaExtra" en el input se me desaparece lo que tengo en el value

Comment: @SantiagoRodriguez ¿Estás usando angular? Te sería más sencillo así

Comment: Si, lo estaba intentado, pero no me cargaba lo que habia en el value, que debe venir directo de la BD.

Comment: Me refería a que usando angular puede ser más sencillo (no que mi solución sea la mejor para angular, no quiero que haya malentendidos).

Comment: @SantiagoRodriguez a qué te refieres con restar el total? Restársela a algún otro campo?

Comment: Y sin relación alguna con la pregunta/respuesta, te llamas igual que un humorista español muy bueno. :-P

Comment: jajajaj Gracias, si, si me referia a restar el total de los campos, lo hice creando otra funcion. Te agradezco de antemano tu ayuda